# php script only being server to two clients at a time

Tags: php

I wrote the following script as a test and it appears it's only being server to two clients at a time:

```
<?php
$time = time();
$timediff = 0;

do
{
    $timediff = time() - $time;
    usleep(1);
}while($timediff <= 1);

echo date('G:i:s', $time)." - ".date('G:i:s', time()); 
?>
```

Result for a LAMP server:

[image: lamp_results]

Each thread seems to be correctly `started` at the same time, confirmed by the `result` (what php echo'd back) and every 2 new threads to indeed take an extra 2 seconds (`time`) to finish.

Each script seems to be taking 2 seconds to finish, after which the following 2 are served. This is just stupid, because now I have a quad core 3.2 GHz server with 12GB RAM queueing people for no good reason. It may be worth to mention that according to `htop` (a system monitor) only two CPU cores are being used by apache2.

I tried the script again on a debian-squeeze server running lighttpd and php5-fpm, which is a completely different setup, but it gave the same results. I'm not sure if it's bad coding or something else..

I already tried commenting out the `usleep()` but that nets the exact same results, except for the fact that `htop` then shows CPU usage at 100% on all (both) cores. With usleep on `1` it shows a usage of 15% on each core, and with usleep on `500` it's barely reaching 6% each, confirming that the server should be able to serve way more pages than 2 at a time.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try a widely used benchmarking tool (e.g. [ApacheBench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) to test the capacity of the server instead of what you are using.  I don't see any reason the server would only handle 2 clients at a time by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you running those tests?  If your benchmarking-software only does 2 requests simultaneously, it makes sense you only get 2 at a time.

You could try out *ab* also known as *apache benchmark*.  You can set the amount of simultaneous request using a parameter.

Comment: ab shows a different result.. must be the benchmarking software I'm using and not the script ór the webserver. How strange.. I'll try to figure it out, thank you ;)

Comment: It did seem a bit strange that such a beast and two different webservers would only allow for 2 simultaneous requests :)